# Passing list of values as parameters in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js and I need help..
I am trying to create a page which shows details of a team

```
import React from "react";

import "../styles/team.css";
import bs from "../images/girl.jpg";
import { membercard } from "./teamcard";

export const Team = () => {
  const user = {
    name: "sowmi",
    email: "sddsd",
    src: { bs },
    designation: "sgsfgsfg",
  };
  return (
    <section className="team">
      <div className="container text-center">
        <h1 className="py-3">MEET OUR AMAZING TEAM</h1>
        <p className="p1">
          This the paragraph where you can write more details about your team
        </p>
        <div className="row">
          <membercard {...user} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

This is my Team.js file

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/team.css";

export const membercard = ({ user }) => {
  const [src, name, email, designation] = this.user;
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4">
      <img src={src} className="image-fluid" alt="" />
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <small>{designation}</small>
      <div className="row">
        <div id="email">
          <span>
            <i
              className="fas fa-envelope-square"
              style={{ fontSize: "20px", padding: "10px" }}
            ></i>
            Email : {email}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is teamcard.js file

So say I want to display 3 members with their details .I want to reuse teamcard.js component,I need to know how I can pass the values as parameters from team.js to teamcard.js

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: I think there is a **user** has an array of object then you can pass the whole array in the teamcard.js after that you have done the **map** in the teamcard.js So your issue has been solved

Comment: no it doesnt work thats y i have asked for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a list of users and pass each one to the component.  One note though, by spreading the user values with `...user` your props are going to come in as `({ name, email, src, designation })`.  They way it's set up now you'll want to pass the full user as a prop.

```
export const Team = () => {
  const users = [
{
    name: "sowmi",
    email: "sddsd",
    src: { bs },
    designation: "sgsfgsfg",
  },
{
    name: "user2",
    email: "sassdf",
    src: { sdfsdf },
    designation: "vbnvbnvbn",
  },

]
  return (
    <section className="team">
      <div className="container text-center">
        <h1 className="py-3">MEET OUR AMAZING TEAM</h1>
        <p className="p1">
          This the paragraph where you can write more details about your team
        </p>
        {users.map(u => 
          <div className="row" key={u.email}>
           <member  user={u} />|
          </div>
         )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using some of the class methods to access props when you're using Functional Components.

Click the **"Run Code Snipper"** button below to see it working.

```js
// Notice the spread operators ({ }) here that are extracting the key from the object user passed
const MemberCard = ({ src, name, email, designation }) => {

  // Alternatively you could do:
  // MemberCard = (props) => {
  // const { src } = props;

  return (<div className="col-lg-4">
    <img src={src} className="image-fluid" alt="" />
      <h5>{name}</h5>
      <small>{designation}</small>
      <div className="row">
        <div id="email">
          <span>
            <i
              className="fas fa-envelope-square"
              style={{ fontSize: "20px", padding: "10px" }}
            ></i>
            Email : {email}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>)
 };

const Team = () => {
  // Notice the change too for the 'src' for the image as well
  const user = {
    name: "sowmi",
    email: "sddsd",
    src: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240',
    designation: "sgsfgsfg",
  };
  return (
    <section className="team">
      <div className="container text-center">
        <h1 className="py-3">MEET OUR AMAZING TEAM</h1>
        <p className="p1">
          This the paragraph where you can write more details about your team
        </p>
        <div className="row">
          <MemberCard {...user} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Team />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```